# How can I customize or mask nextjs page url address?

Tags: next.js

[image]
[image]
I want my url and my pages name to be different from each other in nextjs.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try Something like above and use Router as

```
 Router.push(`/[slug]`, `/example-page`)
```

or if the page name comes from API try as

```
 Router.push(`/[slug]`, `/${data.slug}`)
```

Refer Dynamic Routing concepts in NextJS